# How to convert specflow or cucumber example into keyvaluepair

Tags: c#, cucumber, specflow, feature-file

How to get selenium example as key value so that I can execute step based on example

Comment: I'm glad that you found an answer to your question, and decided to share it with the community. Unfortunately, since your question lacks context and a [repro], it is difficult for other readers to know when this would be an appropriate solution, or even if the problem in your question applies to their problem. Can you [edit] your question to include more information, which should include all relevant C# code and the Gherkin in your feature? You can paraphrase your real Gherkin to create a similar example.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IDictionary<string,string> ConvertExampleToDic()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> keyval = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    List<string> values = new List<string>();

    foreach (var value in _scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Arguments.Values)
    {
       values.Add(value.ToString());
    }
    List<string> keys = new List<string>();
    foreach (var key in _scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Arguments.Keys)
    {
        keys.Add(key.ToString());
    }

    for(int i=0; i< keys.Count;i++)
    {
        keyval.Add(keys[i], values[i]);
    }
    return keyval;
}
```

Comment: And then can you expand on why the code in this answer solves the problem in the question? To be honest, I'm curious to know the problem and why this is the solution. I write a fair amount of Gherkin using SpecFlow. I like to cruise the [tag:specflow] tag. I frequently come across issues I wouldn't have thought about.

Comment: Is `_scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Arguments` **not** a dictionary already?

Comment: And why is the `<foo>` syntax for specifying an value from the example table not working for your use case?

Answer (score 0):

The [ScenarioInfo.Arguments](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/blob/8e0e7d4cecacc0dd3267f12c34477c30c84a2c37/TechTalk.SpecFlow/ScenarioInfo.cs#L27) property is an instance of IOrderedDictionary where the keys and values are of type `object`. This should practically be a one-liner to convert this to `IDictionary<string, string>`:

```
var scenarioArgs = _scenarioContext.ScenarioInfo.Arguments;
var data = scenarioArgs.ToDictionary(item => item.Key.ToString(), item => item.Value.ToString());
```